# Given a divergence free vector Field, how can I find the related vector potential without guesswork?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, vector-fields

I am reading through Griffith's Electrodynamics 4e cover to cover, skipping no sections and doing all of the problems (sans the ones for masochists) as a passion project.

I came to problem 1.53, in which I must find a vector potential A such that
$$
F=\nabla \times A
$$
Given that $F=x^2\hat{x}+3xz^2\hat{y}-2xz\hat{z}$, and that $A_x, A_y, A_z$ are the x, y, and z components of the vector potential A, respectively.

After my initial attempt of trying to equate the components of F with the components of the curl(A) and trying to integrate to obtain A_x, A_y, and A_z from the partials (essentially, followed the solution to problem 1.50 in this link https://physicsisbeautiful.com/resources/introduction-to-electrodynamics/problems/1.50/solutions/1.50-1.51.pdf/wVKSeo2RpyFGeobAJcwXh4/)

After setting all the terms that show up from integrating to zero (which is allowed, right?), I obtained a vector potential of

$$
A=(xz^3-2xyz,-\frac{3}{2}x^2z,\frac{1}{2}x^2y-\frac{3}{2}x^2z^2)
$$

Which does **not** satisfy the condition of F= curl(A). It does have some similar pieces to the

I checked what ever internet solutions I could get my hands on, the textbook solutions, stemjock, physicsisbeautiful, and even this website. Many of the solutions just simplified it with "choose (this term) to be zero" without any sort of explanation. I was not happy with these hand-wavy guess-work answers (unfortunately. I would be much farther along in my cover-to-cover journey had I accepted them).

I decided to try the procedure described in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator.
My work is shown here:

$$
\nabla \times F = -6xz\hat{x}+2z\hat{y}+3z^2\hat{z}
$$

Which means that

$$F_1(xt,yt,zt)=-6xzt^2$$
$$F_2(xt,yt,zt)=2zt$$
$$F_3(xt,yt,zt)=3z^2t^2$$

Plugging these into the integrals for $G_1, G_2, G_3$, I obtain values of

$$G_1=\frac{2}{3}z^2-\frac{3}{4}yz^2$$
$$G_2=\frac{9}{4}xz^2$$
$$G_3=-\frac{3}{2}xyz-\frac{2}{3}xz$$

Edit: In the 2nd link, the question asked is how one can use the components of F to find A (at least, that's what I understood and that's what I'm looking for). However, his example starts with the vector H. Then, he takes the curl of H, uses the components as his $F_1,F_2,F3$, then, uses the formula to undo the curl(H). Doesn't this just give him... H instead of F?

So here we are, yet again with another post on asking about solving for vector potentials. I have already looked at many stack exchange posts that talk about problems like this and found that they did not do it for me and this specific problem.

If anyone can provide a resource that goes through a similar problem, that may be all I need to set this problem to rest and come up with my own solution to this problem.

Comment: I don’t get it, what’s wrong with the integration approach in the other link? That gives you a systematic few integrals to evaluate and voila you get your vector potential. If you’re trying to “write all vector potentials explicitly” you can forget about that dream since the set of all such vector potentials forms an infinite dimensional affine space (the difference between any two is the gradient of some smooth function on $\Bbb{R}^3$) so you can’t write them all out. Your best bet is to do some clever guess work to get one vector potential or grind through a few integrals.

Comment: If you are referring to the first link; I ended up with an A that did not return me to my original vector field F after taking the curl of A. Following my intuition, I got something that was *close* to one of the answers for A described in griffiths' solution manual, but no amount of playing around got me to the answer. I exhausted many resources before posting this problem. I'll try both methods mentioned above once more before writing this one off perhaps.

As for the second link, I don't know what to say other than its possible that I made a mistake. Maybe there's a condition I forgot.

Comment: I was referring to the second link (MSE one which briefly mentioned Poincare’s lemma). Anyway, for the first one it depends how you did things, especially with “setting constants to zero” because you may have actually set a function equal to zero and that’s a big no no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment:
$$
\mathbf{F}=\begin{pmatrix}x^2\\3xz^2\\-2xz\end{pmatrix}\,,
\quad \mathbf{A}=\int_0^1t\,\mathbf{F}(t\,\mathbf{x})\,dt\times\mathbf{x}
$$
solves $\mathbf{F}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$ (albeit not uniquely) and gives
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{A}&=\int_0^1\begin{pmatrix}t^3x^2\\3t^4xz^2\\-2t^3xz\end{pmatrix}\,dt\times
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}x^2/4\\3xz^2/5\\-xz/2\end{pmatrix}\times
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}3xz^3/5+xyz/2\\-x^2z/2-x^2z/4\\x^2y/4-3x^2z^2/5\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\frac{x}{20}\begin{pmatrix}12z^3+10yz\\-15xz\\5xy-12xz^2\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Perfect, this clears it up for me. Thanks for your help and time, Kurt!